Rellenar matriz con "X" según valores de una tabla
Necesito hacer en Excel lo que os explico a continuación:

Tengo una tabla con 2 campos, Fecha y parcela
Tengo una matriz, con el dia del mes en las columnas y las parcelas en las filas

Necesito rellenar con una "X" la celdas de la matriz, cuyos valores coinciden con los pares de la tabla
Podeis ayudarme???
Muchas gracias
Siguiendo vuestros consejos, detallo mas la pregunta:

Me dan la siguiente tabla (solo los campos en amarillo, el resto lo he puesto yo para mi cutre-solucion)


Y tengo que rellenar esta matriz, colocando una "R" donde se cruzen dia y parcela, con los datos de la tabla anterior:



Lo he conseguido de forma muy cutre, mediante "COINCIDIR", con esa saco las columnas "COLUMNA" y "FILA", y luego en la matriz, en cada celda tengo un "BUSCARV", etc....
Funciona pero no es nada ético ni funcional
Alguna solución que mejore (no es muy dificil mejorarla jejeje) esta solucion???
Muchas gracias!!!

Deberías exponer mejor tu pregunta y dar detalles de lo que has intentado y dónde falla. Como elaborar una buena pregunta
Puedes añadir también alguna imagen de lo que tienes y lo que necesitas obtener.

Gracias por tus consejos. Acabo de editar la pregunta con la idea de hacerla mas comprensible. Un saludo

Partiendo de una hoja datos como esta:

Y de una hoja matriz como esta:

Te paso el código que hace lo que pides. Pégalo en un módulo:
Public dFechas As Object

Sub CargaDatos()
    
    'Creo un diccionario público con claves unívocas concatenando fecha y parcela
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim arrDatos As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim clave As String
    
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wk.Sheets("datos")
    arrDatos = sh.UsedRange
    Set dFechas = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrDatos)
        clave = arrDatos(i, 1) & arrDatos(i, 2) 'Fecha & Parcela
        If Not dFechas.Exists(clave) Then dFechas.Add clave, 1
    Next
    
    Set arrDatos = Nothing
    
End Sub

Sub CompletaMatriz()

    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim FilaInicio As Integer, ColumnaInicio As Integer
    Dim uf As Long
    Dim uc As Integer
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim clave As String
      
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wk.Sheets("matriz")
    'Defino las dimensiones de la matriz
    FilaInicio = 6
    ColumnaInicio = 3
    'Almaceno la última columna (uc) con datos y la última fila (uf) con datos
    uc = sh.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    uf = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    'Recorro la matriz
    For i = FilaInicio To uf
      For x = ColumnaInicio To uc
          clave = sh.Cells(5, x) & sh.Cells(i, 2)     'Concatenando la fecha de la columna y la parcela de la fila creo una clave con el mismo formato que la usada en el diccionario dFechas
          If dFechas.Exists(clave) Then sh.Cells(i, x) = "R"  'Si la clave de la matriz existe en el diccionario dFechas pongo una R
      Next
    Next
    
    sh.Activate
    
    MsgBox "Proceso finalizado!"


End Sub

Sub Main()
    Call CargaDatos
    Call CompletaMatriz
End Sub

Ejecutando el código de Main queda algo así:

Espero que sea útil.

Muchas gracias!!! Funciona perfectamente!!!

Por favor, si te ha funcionado marca la respuesta como correcta.
Gracias.

Lo que buscas es muy fácil de implementar. Básicamente necesitas la función CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO.

Función
CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO

Fíjate que tú en realidad quieres contar si para una fecha concreta y parcela específica existen filas de datos. Si la cuenta es mayor que 0, devolver R, y nada en caso contrario.

En la celda E2 la fórmula es:
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:$A$43;E$1;$B$2:$B$43;$D2)

Esto nos devuelve la cantidad de filas que existen para una fecha y parcela específicas. Se puede personalizar un poco más con un SI condicional para obtener lo que quieres:

Ahora la fórmula es:
=SI(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:$A$43;E$1;$B$2:$B$43;$D2)>0;"R";"")

Así de sencillo y fácil. Solo tienes que tener cuidado a la hora de fijar las referencias en la fórmula, pero es bastante sencillo.
